# (Vue 3) How to set icon image by background property in css?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3

**How to set image with background property that is in public folder?**

```
|_public
| |_images
|   |_icon.png
|_src
  |_components
    |_TheHeader.vue
```

I'm tring to set image into `TheHeader.vue` with background property in css but the image in `public` folder.

```
**vue**

<template>
 <input type="text" :style="background">
</template>

<script>
export default {
 computed: {
  background() {
   return { 
    'background': `url(${require('/images/search-icon.png')}) 5px center no-repeat;` 
   }
  }
 }
}
</script>


Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/images/search-icon.png' in C:/user...
```

even absolute path doesnt work

```
<style scoped>
input {
 background: url('../../../public/search-icon.png') 5px center no-repeat;
}
<style>
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../public/search-icon.png' in 'C:\user...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one path you have `'../../../public/search-icon.png'` and in the other it's `'/images/search-icon.png'` so it's not clear if the search-icon is in an `images` folder or not.  Assuming it is, the below code should work:

```js
background() {
  return {
    background: `url('/public/images/search-icon.png') 5px center no-repeat`
  }
}
```

or

```css
input {
  background: url('/public/images/search-icon.png') 5px center no-repeat;
}
```

`../../public/images/search-icon.png` should also work. Looks like you went up 1 directory level too far with your relative path.